# How do you have the create Action route to an alternative model name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Routes.rb

> resources :recovers match ':checkedin'
>   => 'recovers#index' match ':checkin/:id' => 'recovers#show'

When a new record is created Rails routes the user to /recovers, I would like the user to be routed to /checkedin how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

routes.db:

```
resources :recovers
match 'checkedin' => 'recovers#index', :as => 'checkedin'
match 'checkin/:id' => 'recovers#show'
```

recovers_controller.rb:
in the create method:

```
redirect_to checkedin_path
```